# Java Rest API working on localhost but not on server

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, ubuntu-18.04

I developed a Java RestAPI to update some values in the MongoDB database and returning a string saying "Values are updated". API is working fine in the localhost and returning the string. But when I deployed the application in the ubuntu server and trying to update the values in the same way as given in the localhost, It is returning the string "Values are updated" but no changes are reflected in the database.

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04

What would be the issue for this?

edit:

This is my controller

```java
@PutMapping("/updateGroupMessageSeenMembers") 
public String updateGroupMessageSeenMembers(@RequestBody UpdateMessageSeenMembersDTO updateMessageSeenMembersDTO ){
    return groupService.updateGroupMessageSeenMembers(updateMessageSeenMembersDTO);
}
```

this is my serviceImpl logic:

```java
@Override
public String updateGroupMessageSeenMembers(UpdateMessageSeenMembersDTO updateMessageSeenMembersDTO) {

    List<GroupChatEntity> groupChatList = groupChatRepository.getChatByRecieverId(updateMessageSeenMembersDTO.getGroup_id());
    long readRcvr = groupChatList.stream().map(m -> {
        Query query1 = new Query(Criteria.where("sender_id").is(m.getSender_id()))
              .addCriteria(Criteria.where("reciever_id").is(m.getReciever_id()));
        int updateCnt=0;
        for(int i=0;i<updateMessageSeenMembersDTO.getParticipates().size();i++) {
            UpdateResult result= mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query1, new Update().addToSet("message_read_people",
                         updateMessageSeenMembersDTO.getParticipates().get(i)), GroupChatEntity.class);
            updateCnt=updateCnt+(int)result.getModifiedCount();
        }
        return updateCnt;
    }).count();
    return "Values are updated";
        
}
```

What would be the reason for this please suggest?

Comment: I can't see where you return "Values are updated" in the code you posted

Comment: I've made an edit please check @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Can you check what the output is if you change `return "Values are updated";` to `return "Values are updated. Update count: " + readRcvr ;`. Reason is that I suspect you update nothing (due to database error), but assume it's correct because you have no feedback.